# ruby popen4 command runs via shell which causes issues when arguments contain spaces

Tags: ruby, regex, popen

I have a custom launcher app that uses popen4. The script passes everything after the double hyphen at the end '--' into popen4 and I use the std out abilities to do some custome piping and statistics gathering.

The issue arises when the script we are launching takes an argument that includes spaces.

```
my_launcher.rb --keep-alive --log-file /path/file.log -- /launch/this/script.rb --foo "param with spaces"
```

The shell strips off the quotes around "param with spaces", and because popen4 only accepts strings, there is no way to add these back on without doing some regexp work that I worry will introduce bugs.

'regular' popen provides a way to pass the command as an array and thus bypass the shell, but this does not appear to be implemented in popen4.

---

From the rdoc for ruby IO

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html

If cmd is a String “-”, then a new instance of Ruby is started as the subprocess.

If cmd is an Array of String, then it will be used as the subprocess’s argv bypassing a shell.

---

Is there a way to access the 'shell bypassing' feature that popen uses and pass that object to popen4?

Or, is there a way to take the array of strings, and format it with encased quotes where appropriate so that params that include spaces are recognized as one argument? I could then pass this string to popen4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the shellwords module

```
 require 'shellwords'
 args = [ '/launch/this/script.rb', '--foo', 'param with spaces' ]
 popen4( Shellwords.join( args ) )
```